# Return a zigzag array

Tags: java

I have two questions:

```
public static int[] everyOther(int[] arr)
```

Given an integer array arr, create and return a new array that contains precisely the elements in the even-numbered positions in the array arr. Make sure that your method works correctly for arrays of both odd and even lengths, and for arrays that contain zero or only one element. The length of the result array that you return must be exactly right so that there are no extra zeros at the end of the array.

```
public static int[][] createZigZag(int rows, int cols, int start)
```

This method creates and returns a new two-dimensional integer array, which in Java is really just a one-dimensional array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays of type int[]. The returned array must have the correct number of rows that each have exactly cols columns. This array must contain the numbers start, start + 1, ..., start + (rows * cols - 1) in its rows in order, except that the elements in each odd-numbered row must be listed in descending order.

For example, when called with rows = 4, cols = 5 and start = 4, this method should create and return the two-dimensional array whose contents are

```
 4     5     6     7     8
13    12    11    10     9
14    15    16    17    18
23    22    21    20    19
```

when displayed in the traditional matrix form that is more readable for the human than the more realistic form of a one-dimensional array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays of rows.

```
public static int[] everyOther(int[] arr){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < aList.size() ; i+=2)
    {
        return( aList.get(i) + "  ") ;
    }               
}

public static int[][] createZigZag(int rows, int cols, int start){
    { 
        int evenRow = 0; 
        int oddRow = 1;  

        while (evenRow < rows)  
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) 
            { 
                return(start[evenRow][i] + " ");  
            } 

            evenRow = evenRow + 2;  

            if(oddRow < rows) 
            { 
            for (int i = cols - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {  
                return(start[oddRow][i] + " ");  
            } 
            } 
            oddRow = oddRow + 2;  
        }  
    }
}
```

does this make sense?

Comment: No. This doesn't make sense. Your methods are supposed to return `int[]` and `int[][]`. You aren't returning anything and instead printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an attempted solution to your exercise.

*Notes:*

- If you copy paste this whole code, make sure your class file is named `TestExample` as is this one.
- Inside `main` method are just some tests so that you see the output printed and you can verify it. You can ignore `Arrays.toString()`, it's just to print the `int[]` arrays to the screen in a better format.
- Wherever you see `final`, you can ignore it or erase it (for now, that you still learn the language). In a simple first look, it means you don't intend to change this variable. After you proceed in learning the language, visit this again but this time consider that it "locks" the variable name to a specific reference inside the enclosing scope. It doesn't guarantee immutability of the value however except if it is a primitive value (int, long, float, double etc).
- Notice that the arrays have to have been initialized (their dimensions) before you assign any value to a specific position of the array.
- For the `everyOther` method, note that Java is zero-based in its indexing and thus in the array `new int[] { 8, 9, 10, 11 };` your first odd-indexed value is `9` and the second is `11`.

*General advice:* If you are now starting with a language, use an IDE like Eclipse (it's free & open source), IntelliJ (free) or NetBeans(free & open source). It would red-underline the errors in your code and (if configured) display warning messages as well for dangerous practices.

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestExample
{
    public static int[][] createZigZag(final int rows, final int cols, int start)
    {
        final int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = start;
                start++;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] everyOther(final int[] array)
    {
        int otherArrayLength;
        if (array.length % 2 == 0)
        {
            otherArrayLength = array.length / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            otherArrayLength = array.length / 2 + 1;
        }
        final int[] otherArray = new int[otherArrayLength];

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2)
        {
            otherArray[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
        return otherArray;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final int[] testArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        final int[] everyOtherArray = everyOther(testArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(everyOtherArray));

        final int rows = 4;
        final int cols = 5;
        final int start = 4;
        final int[][] zigzagArray = createZigZag(rows, cols, start);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(zigzagArray[i]));
        }
    }
}
```